# update an existing row with new rows and data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have simply

```
CREATE table1
(
  common INT, 
  var1 VARCHAR, 
  var2 VARCHAR, 
  var3 VARCHAR,
  var4 VARCHAR,
  var5 VARCHAR,
  var6 VARCHAR
)
CREATE table2
(
  common INT,
  var4 VARCHAR,
  var5 VARCHAR,
  var6 VARCHAR
)

INSERT table1 VALUE(0,"test1","test2","test3",NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT table2 VALUE(0,"test4","test5","test6")
```

What I'm trying to get in table1's 1st row or where common = 0:

```
row1:
common = 0,
var1 = "test1",
var2 = "test2",
var3 = "test3",
var4 = "test4",
var5 = "test5",
var6 = "test6"
```

Instead I get:

```
row1:
common = 0,
var1 = "test1",
var2 = "test2",
var3 = "test3",
var4 = NULL,
var5 = NULL,
var6 = NULL

row2:
common = 0,
var1 = NULL,
var2 = NULL,
var3 = NULL,
var4 = "test4",
var5 = "test5",
var6 = "test6"
```

I've tried using an INSERT INTO.. SELECT statement but only get new rows not new data in table1's rows where common = 0

```
INSERT INTO table1 (table1.var4,table1.var5,table1.var6)
SELECT  table2.var4, table2.var5, table2.var6
FROM table2
WHERE common = 0
```

I understand why this only adds a row but is there a way to update an existing row with new rows and data from another table in more or less the same fashion?

Comment: Can we see the actual CREATE TABLE statements instead of these pseudo statements?

Comment: I figured common would be a dead giveaway for the Primary_Key, rest is basic ints and charvars

Comment: Charvars aren't a thing

Comment: OMG, I'm sorry VARCHARS, does it make sense to you now?

Comment: While that might be true, I don't think that's the real problem

Comment: LMAO, there is no problem, I figured it out no thanks to you.  What was your input?  How did you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So often I find myself answering my own questions

```
UPDATE table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.common = b.common
SET a.var4=b.var4,a.var5=b.var5,a.var6=b.var6
WHERE a.common=b.common
```

does exactly what I needed and follows suit with the simple syntax of the INSERT statement.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if allowed, and thereby close this question

Comment: If I was allowed I would have, thanks for the go ahead though.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an after INSERT trigger  ON table2 and inside update table 1

Like

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_members_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON table2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE table1 SET var4 = NEW.var4,var5 = NEW.var5,var6 = NEW.var6
    WHERE common = NEw.common 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If the column in table1 doesn't exists, you will loose the insert.

If you want to insert  a new row in table1, you wmust check with

> IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE common = NEW.common) THEM

if a column already exists. and then deside what to do.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, as opposed to down voting and then giving no real input.  It may work but I was looking for something simpler.

Comment: that is simple, so you have only two INSERT querys with your solution you need 3 that is not simpler in my eyes

Comment: You think your answer was simple?  Maybe if I have another few months or so of practice with all the different syntax sure.  Is it close to what I asked for?  No, not really, you can see the clear similarities in syntax between an insert statement and my answer.

Comment: No they are equal and vecause they do exactly the same.mine does it automatically and you have do do this by hand, for every insert table 2, .

Comment: Again, I was looking for a simple syntax closer to an insert statement, which yours is clearly not.  Mine is done using 5 Key Words yours requires 11+.  I am just starting out with MySQL, your answer would require Google to understand, mine is pretty straight forward.  Get it?  Unlike most I'm not looking for an answer I'm looking to understand.