# How do I both update rows in and add new rows to a table from another table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, aws-glue

[Using SQL query on AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/transforms-sql.html), I'm creating a job to merge a latest CSV file (i.e., `UpdatedCustomer`) into a *running total* CSV file (i.e., `Customer`), both of which have the same schema. The latest CSV file can have either new records or records to be updated in the running total CSV. Both these files are represented as SQL tables, which can be queried using [Apache SparkSQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref.html).

Given `Customer` and `UpdatedCustomer`, I'd like to get `FinalCustomer` where row with `CustomerID = 1` got its `CustomerName` updated, and a new record with `CustomerID = 4` was added. All the other rows remain untouched.

Table `Customer`:

| CustomerID | CustomerName | ContactName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alfreds Futterkiste | Maria Anders |
| 2 | Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados | Ana Trujillo |
| 3 | Antonio Moreno Taquería | Antonio Moreno |

Table `UpdatedCustomer`:

| CustomerID | CustomerName | ContactName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mariand Inc | Maria Anders |
| 4 | Artic Ice | Leon Idas |

Then table `FinalCustomer` should be:

| CustomerID | CustomerName | ContactName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mariand Inc | Maria Anders |
| 2 | Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados | Ana Trujillo |
| 3 | Antonio Moreno Taquería | Antonio Moreno |
| 4 | Artic Ice | Leon Idas |

---

Using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61238058/10824322):

```sql
UPDATE Customer a 
INNER JOIN UpdateCustomer b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
SET a.CustomerName = b.CustomerName, a.ContactName = b.ContactName
WHERE a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

I get common row(s) updated, however it's unclear to me how I'd go about adding the new row in `UpdatedCustomer` as well.

Comment: "it doesn't get me what I want": Please elaborate.

Comment: We don't know for what DBMS you are seeking a solution. Please tag your request with your SQL. As you want to merge data and not only update rows, you are probably looking for `MERGE` instead of `UPDATE`. `MERGE` is standard SQL and  available in many DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There are problems with MERGE. Mainly, it's more like an IF/ELSE block for multiple queries, and does not guarantee any kind of atomicity or transactional integrity. It's sad, but we are typically better off manually implementing an UPSERT pattern in a transaction.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've specified that SQL queries on a AWS Glue job use [Apache SparkSQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single SQL command to do this in one statement.

There is [`MERGE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)), which *seems like* it should do the job, but this is deceptive. MERGE does not guarantee any kind of atomicity or transactional integrity, and instead creates more of pre-structured IF/ELSE block where you still need to write both the INSERT and UPDATE queries in full.

Instead, we are typically better off manually implementing an UPSERT pattern inside a transaction. What that looks like exactly depends on what driver or medium you are using the process the CSV files as SQL tables. Just telling us "AWS Glue" is not enough information to know how this was done.